# How to properly set optional boolean parameter for pic in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, optional-arguments, tikz-pic, arguments, variable

I try to draw beam on tikz with the possibility to hide its axis.

I created the following:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, shadings}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\tikzset{
    pics/beam/.style args={L #1 D #2 show axis #3}{
        code = {
            \tikzmath{
                \L = #1; % beam length
                \D = #2; % beam diameter
                \showAxis = "#3"; % yes if axis should be drawn, otherwise no
            }
            \begin{scope}[name prefix=beam pic]
                \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (beam end) at (\L, 0);
                \coordinate (p1) at (0, -\D/2);
                \coordinate (p2) at (\L, \D/2);
                
                \shadedraw [top color = gray, bottom color = gray, middle color = white] (p1) rectangle (p2);
                
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\showAxis}{yes}}{
                    \draw (origin) -- (-3.5, 0);
                    \draw [dash pattern = on 10 mm off 1 mm on 1 pt off 1 mm]  (0,0) -- (\L,0);
                    \draw (beam end) -- ++(3.5, 0);
                }{}
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
        \draw (0,0) pic {beam = L 70 D 12 show axis yes};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result is fine, but my code not. I dislike 2 things: first, `show axis` parameter is not boolean and I have no ideas how to make it boolean, because I started to use tikz last Saturday. Second, it's not good to write `show axis = yes` every time I use `pic {beam}`. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591271/multiple-named-arguments-to-tikz-pic-using-keys/591290#591290), demonstrating, that it's possible to use boolean optional parameter for `pic`. Also I saw [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468850/how-to-pass-boolean-value-to-a-tikz-option-key). I tried to adopt code from these posts but have a lot of errors. I can't understand why my code doesn't work because I use tikz only during for a week.

My code is:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newif\ifShowAxis

\tikzset{
    pics/beam/.style = {
        code = {
            \tikzset{circle pyramid/.cd,#1}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/circle pyramid options/L}\L
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/circle pyramid options/D}\D
            \begin{scope}[name prefix=beam pic]
                \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (beam end) at (\L, 0);
                \coordinate (p1) at (0, -\D/2);
                \coordinate (p2) at (\L, \D/2);
                
                \shadedraw [top color = gray, bottom color = gray, middle color = white] (p1) rectangle (p2);
                
                \ifShowAxis
                    \draw (origin) -- (-3.5, 0);
                    \draw [dash pattern = on 10 mm off 1 mm on 1 pt off 1 mm]  (0,0) -- (\L,0);
                    \draw (beam end) -- ++(3.5, 0);
                \fi
            \end{scope}
        }
    },
    beam/.cd,
    L/.initial = 80,
    D/.initial = 12,
    show axis/.is if = ifShowAxis,
    show axis = true,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
        \draw (0,0) pic {beam};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/simple-example-of-pgfkeys/114017#114017), that helped me a lot.

So, we can use smth. like the following code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newif\ifshowaxis

\tikzset{
    beam parameters/.is family,
    beam parameters,
    L/.initial = 80, % beam length
    D/.initial = 12, % beam diameter
    show axis/.is if = showaxis, % not ifshowaxis!
    show axis = true,
}

\tikzset{
    pics/beam/.style = {
        code = {
            \tikzset{
                beam parameters/.cd,#1,
                L/.get = \L,
                D/.get = \D,
            }
            \begin{scope}[name prefix=beam pic]
                \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (beam end) at (\L, 0);
                \coordinate (p1) at (0, -\D/2);
                \coordinate (p2) at (\L, \D/2);
                
                \shadedraw [top color = gray, bottom color = gray, middle color = white] (p1) rectangle (p2);
                
                \ifshowaxis
                    \draw (origin) -- (-3.5, 0);
                    \draw [dash pattern = on 10 mm off 1 mm on 1 pt off 1 mm]  (0,0) -- (\L,0);
                    \draw (beam end) -- ++(3.5, 0);
                \fi
            \end{scope}
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
        \draw (0,0) pic {beam};
        
        \draw (0, -20) pic {beam={show axis = false}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Shortly, we create keys family, named `beam parameters` and then use these keys in  `beam` pic code.

If you check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591271/multiple-named-arguments-to-tikz-pic-using-keys/591290#591290), you may notice, that there is no keys family before pic code. I still can't understand and adopt code in this answer for my beam, but at least I solved my problem in a similar way.