Making a lot of slightly different versions of a PDF with LaTeX
I need to create a large number (say 20) of versions of PDF documents that are slightly different, that come from one LaTeX document.
What I envisage is some kind of custom labels that are interpreted when the document is compiled to PDF. For document #1, the text inside a certain "custom1" label will be hidden (as if it were just a code comment) but everything else will show. For PDF #2, the text inside a "custom2" label will be hidden. And so on to #20.
My question is the same as this one, except there the asker only wants to create two PDF documents, and I think the replies are generally only good for that binary.

Welcome! Doesn't the answer concerning xcomment do what you want?

You could use the comment package mentioned in this answer of your linked question.  Document #1 would have \excludecomment{custom1} and \includecomment all the others.  You would probably want to automate the compilation of the 20 though.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705487/ might be useful. (Disclaimer: I authored that answer.) I'd look at the xcomment answer first, though.

Here are a few options for creating documents with conditional content. However, I think what you want is package multiaudience:

you can set the audience in your document and compile (creates 1 pdf)
you can run a batch compile for all defined audiences (creates all pdfs)
see its manual for details

Here's a simple example:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multiaudience}

% ~~~ define all audiences ~~~~~~~~~
\SetNewAudience{cust1}
\SetNewAudience{cust2}
\SetNewAudience{cust3}

% ~~~ select the current one for this compile ~~~
%     (or use the commandline option)
\DefCurrentAudience{cust1} % <<< cust1, cust2, cust3

\begin{document}

\begin{shownto}{cust1}
     (+) This is visible to cust1 only.
\end{shownto}

\begin{shownto}{cust2}
    (++)  This is visible to CUst2 only.
\end{shownto}

\begin{shownto}{cust3}
    (+++) This is visible to cuST3 only.
\end{shownto}
 
 
 This is visible to all audiences.
 
 \begin{shownto}{-,cust3}
     (**) This is visible to all, but not cuST3.
\end{shownto}
 
 
\end{document}

With \DefCurrentAudience{cust1} it compiles as:

With \DefCurrentAudience{cust2} it compiles as:

With \DefCurrentAudience{cust3} it compiles as:

Please note that I visualized the customer audienced and the number of legitimate audiences in ( ).
P.S.
You may want to add and try e.g.:
 \begin{shownto}{-,cust3,cust1}
     (*) This is visible to all, but not cuST3 and cust1.
\end{shownto}


I think this is exactly what I want, thanks! I didn't know what to search for.

Fine :) // You described it well, and I also was looking for versioning or comments before I became aware of multiaudience. However, it might be a challenge to keep the documents code clear enough with all those exceptional environments.
